# android - (XmlPullParserFactory) factory.newPullParser(); vs Xml.newPullParser();

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

why are there two ways to instantiate a new XmlPullParser object? First, 
https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory#newPullParser()

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
```

This only sets features present in the factory right? Secondly,
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Xml#newPullParser()

```
XmlPullParser xpp = xpp = Xml.newPullParser();
```

Is the only difference, that the returned object will have two features? From android.util.Xml.java:

```
KXmlParser parser = new KXmlParser();
parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL, true);
parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, true);
```

Or did I miss something? Thanks